# My Vital UITextField code isn't working

Tags: ios, uitextfield

```
@IBOutlet var prevKg: UITextField!  

@IBOutlet var prevGm: UITextField!  

@IBOutlet var nowKg: UITextField!  

@IBOutlet var nowGm: UITextField!  


@IBOutlet var resultLabelMetric: UILabel!  


@IBAction func findDifMetric(sender: AnyObject) {  


    var enteredPrevKg = prevKg.text.toInt()  

    var enteredPrevGm = prevGm.text.toInt()  

    var enteredNowGm = nowGm.text.toInt()  

    var enteredNowKg = nowKg.text.toInt()
```

I recently cracked open a project that I haven't touched for ages, only to find out some of its vital code isn't working! In this app I have 4 text fields in which you type in numbers, and then press a button to find answers.  Xcode tells me to insert an '!' or '?' after ".text" but then more errors come up . Can anyone help me debug/figure out my problem?

Comment: Can you post what errors are coming up?

Comment: You need to convert those code to latest swift version. There is no other way, go to edit menu and convert the code via the convert option provided by xcode

Comment: @MidhunMP that resolved all the errors, but now when I run to go to the simulator Xcode tells me "the operation couldn't be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0)" do you have any idea what this means?

Comment: Please quit xcode and simulator and check

Comment: @MidhunMP just tried that.. still not working